# How to count rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column like below,

```
ColumnA
Test
Test1
Test3
Test3
Test4
Test
```

So I want to count same values and show them separately like below;

```
ColumnValue    ColumnCount
Test            2
Test3           2
Test1           1
Test4           1
```

How can I do that in Excel?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Looks like a job for a Pivot Table to me. Insert a headerrow if you don't already. Select your data in column A and insert a pivot table. Select the just made header in the pivot fields (you'll notice it gets selected under rows) but also drag the header to *values*. There you have it =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ColumnValue is column D, try the formulae:

- in Column D:

```
=INDEX(A2:A7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,A2:A7),0))
```

- in Column E:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,D2)
```

Drag the formula to fill the other cells.

[image]

Comment: Somehow it throws error. What is D2 exactly? And how the formula can be if ColumnValue  is Column A?

Comment: @yatta See added image on the answer.

Comment: But ColumnValue column is currently empty, it should gather data automatically from ColumnA.

Comment: FYI, the `"=" &` is unneccessary.   The `criteria` argument can be merely `D2`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks. I have modified it.

Comment: @yatta See edit.

Comment: I really don't get it why I'm getting error. I just c/p the formula in D2 cell, but Excel says somethings wrong in the formula.

Comment: @yatta Depending on your setting, you might have to use semi colons instead of commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have Excel O365 with the `UNIQUE` function, you can:

- Create a Table for your data in Column A so the range will auto-expand/contract

  - (*You can use regular addressing if you prefer*)

```
D2:  =UNIQUE(Table4[Column A])
E2:  =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,D2#)
```

- Be sure to use the correct table name in the `D2` formula
- The formula results will spill down as far as needed, so don't drag them down.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, somehow my Excel doesn't support UNIQUE command, but thanks for your helps!